# Issue inserting string datatype into database

Tags: sql, insert, postgresql-9.1

I have the following insert query with a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO Order (time_of_purchase, cust_id) 
VALUES (NOW(), (SELECT cust_id FROM Customer WHERE first_name = "John" AND last_name = "Doe")) RETURNING reference_number
```

When I execute the query, postgres returns the error: "ERROR: column "John" does not exist. SQL state: 42703. Character: 110

What could be the problem?

Comment: Unlike MySQL default settings, proper SQL syntax dictates `"identifier"` and `'string'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Single Quotes` instead of `double quotes`. `"` makes the compiler to consider it as identifier. Try this insert

```
INSERT INTO Order (time_of_purchase, cust_id) 
SELECT NOW(),cust_id FROM Customer WHERE first_name = 'John' AND last_name = 'Doe'
```

Comment: it works.  but what if the first_name and last_name are parameters? Example: INSERT INTO Order (time_of_purchase, cust_id) 
SELECT NOW(),cust_id FROM Customer WHERE first_name = $var1 AND last_name = $var2

Comment: @jpineds Use parameter bindings (aka "prepared statements") then. Refer to the documentation of the Pg database adapter you are using (in PHP).

Comment: can it be achieved without using prepared statements?